# Raspberry Pi onboard temp sensors in Raspbian(Wheezy)?

Tags: raspbian, temperature

I have been looking on the internet and found nothing for getting readings of the temperatures of the CPU on the Raspberry Pi.

Im using Raspbian (Wheezy).

Any help would be great for everyone!

Comment: asked and answered multiple times: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8690/7274

Comment: i didnt want to do jQuery or graphs.

Comment: reading `/sys/class/thermal_zone0/temp` does not require no graphs nor jquery

Comment: but the 2 answers in the question you linked talked about using jQuery or output with graphs. and python.

Comment: please, read the question, the quote starting from "# read the temperature and convert..." and the next 2 lines.

Comment: notice how mine doesnt say "convert". mine is nothing like the one you linked. i just wanted a simple solution. not a html output or a png file of a graph.. the answer i checked is the correct answer. or is the correct output method "CLI".

Comment: If you read the bash example carefully enough, the "conversion" is necessary if you want the temperature in degrees, notice your excepted answer performs this "conversion" as well, it just is not labelled as such (the change is merely to put the decimal point in the right place, a raw reading returns thousands, e.g. `47615` means `47.615 °C`)

Comment: remember not everyone knows how to read bash script.

Comment: lenik told you which lines to look at, you could have just tried them rather than announcing `notice how mine doesnt say "convert". mine is nothing like the one you linked.`, you make it sound like lenik is wrong and gurcanozturk is right, both examples basically do the same thing.

Comment: This doesnt work. the answer i checked works first time. TEMPERATURE=cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
TEMPERATURE=echo -n ${TEMPERATURE:0:2}; echo -n .; echo -n ${TEMPERATURE:2}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found an answer at http://www.raspberrypi.org forums. You can read the CPU temp via bash script. Save this script as getTemp.sh in /usr/local/bin folder and give execute permission with chmod +x /usr/local/bin/getTemp.sh command. Then run it, you will get temp values.

```
#!/bin/bash
cpuTemp0=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
cpuTemp1=$(($cpuTemp0/1000))
cpuTemp2=$(($cpuTemp0/100))
cpuTempM=$(($cpuTemp2 % $cpuTemp1))

echo CPU temp"="$cpuTemp1"."$cpuTempM"'C"
echo GPU $(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp)
```