# A Shortcut For Checking Temps?

Tags: temperature

So I live in California and it is really hot so I worry about my RPI temperatures. I want a really easy way to check right now I have used the GNU Nano program to make a bash alias so when I type temp in the LX Terminal I get my temperature. But I want something faster so I want to make a shortcut so I click it on the desktop and it runs the command in LX Terminal.

Thanks!

Comment: please check this answer: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8690/7274

Answer (score 2):

You can use Conky[1](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) for temperature and other monitoring issues. With Conky, you can get temperature, disk usage, memory consumption, bandwidth etc also it works always on your desktop so you don't have to click to see statistics.

Sample screenshot from [Conky official site](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) :

[image: http://conky.sourceforge.net/conky.png]

Comment: Good idea! Not only **can** (can, mind you) Conky look good, it can also provide easy access to info about your PC (or, in this case, your Pi.) Only thing is, this is another piece of software that the Pi has to handle. Do you know the specs that conky uses (RAM/CPU)? That might make your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click on your desktop and select *Create New Shortcut* from the popup menu:

[image: create new shortcut]

Then, you can input the name of the shortcut you want, the command, and the tooltip, as well as change the logo (not to mention more advanced features.) You'd probably want to check the *Runs in Terminal Emulator* option:

[image: lxshortcut]

In your case you would want it to look somewhat like this:

[image: check the temperature - lxshortcut]

Hope this helps you! If having the command as simply `temp` doesn't work, comment back here and I'll see if I can't figure out why!

Best of luck!

Comment: To reply to: RPi Awesomeness Jul 8 '14 at 12:49 comment, my complete desktop-conky running with the waterproof gpio temperature sensor DS18B20 uses 1% CPU & 13.7 MB RSS & 84.4 MB VM refreshing read out set for every 60 seconds, so I don't think the system resources are overburdened by using conky on my Raspberry Pi 2 model B with this entry in my .conkyrc file in my home folder: RPi Temp Sensor: ${execi 60 cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000007268a94/w1_slave | awk '$NF ~ /t=/ { print substr($NF,3,2) }' }°C (Showing 21C at the moment) True, I haven't tried lm-sensors to display the CPU temperature